# Two ASP.NET applications hosted in same server. Window.open from one application for other application logs out the first application

Tags: asp.net, session, window.open

I have two ASP.NET applications hosted in our server. In first application (say A), I have a hyperlink to open the second application (say B).

I am using window.open to open B.

```
window.open(myurl, "mywindow", "menubar=1,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1");
```

When B is opened, A gets logged out.

I hosted B in another server and opened it from A, now A does not get logged out.

I am pretty sure that it is an issue with session.

I actually need to host both applications in one server. Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Is it form authentication protected?

Comment: Yes. It is forms authentication protected.

Comment: Check if both sites are using same authentication cookie name. If so then you can configure it with different names.

Comment: I am using different cookieNames as suggested in other post here. <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" cookieName="ApplicationASession">     So the default name ASP.NET_SessionId is not used here. I found this using fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session state and forms authentication are 2 different things, and each one has a separate cookie. Session state has nothing to do with whether or not the user is logged in.

You should be adjusting the [Forms Authentication cookie settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiename(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want each application to have a separate cookie name:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    cookieless="UseCookies"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" /> <!-- Change the cookie name here -->
</authentication>
```